# How to call api only on mount and click of Fetch Next User button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, eslint

I have the below code

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, useCallback} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const Users = () => {
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    const [nextPageNumber, setNextPageNumber] = useState(1);

const fetchUsers = useCallback(() => {
    axios.get(`https://randomuser.me/api?page=${nextPageNumber}`).then(response => {
        const updatedUsers = [...users, ...response.data.results];
        setUsers(updatedUsers);
        setNextPageNumber(response.data.info.page + 1);
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    })
}, [nextPageNumber, users])

useEffect(() => {
    fetchUsers();
}, [fetchUsers]);

const fetchNextUser = () => {
    fetchUsers();
}

if(users.length === 0){
    return <div>No Users available</div>
}

return(
    <div>
        <button onClick={fetchNextUser}>Fetch Next user</button>
        {users.map(user => (
            <div key={user.id}>
                <div>Name: {user.name.title} {user.name.first} {user.name.last}</div>
                <div>
                    <img src={user.picture.large} alt="Not available"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        ))}
    </div>
)
}

export default Users;
```

This is calling the api repeatadlly. I have used the fetchUsers dependency in useEffect and useCallback hook due to eslint errors. I just want to call the api on first mount and on click of Fetch Next user button without any eslint error.

Is there any way we can achieve that?

Comment: Well, you have `users` in the dependencies array of `fetchUsers()` therefore it keeps changing every time you call it, causing the `useEffect()` to call it again... hence the infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with the below changes it will not give you the eslint error messages.

import React, {useState, useEffect, useRef, useCallback} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

```
const Users = () => {
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    const nextPageRef = useRef(1)

    const fetchUsers = useCallback(() => {
        axios.get(`https://randomuser.me/api?page=${nextPageRef.current}`).then(response => {
            const updatedUsers = [...response.data.results];
            setUsers(prevUsers => [...prevUsers, ...updatedUsers]);
            nextPageRef.current = response.data.info.page + 1
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        })
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchUsers();
    }, [fetchUsers]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetchUsers();
}, []);
```

This will call the `fetchUsers` function only once.

And when button is pressed, again call the `fetchUsers()` function